# Is there a Google Sheets function to format numbers in scientific notation?

Tags: google-sheets

There are multiple posts online explaining that you can click on a cell and use the `Format > Number` dropdown to change a cell's number to scientific notation.

However, my cell contains a mixture of text and numbers. Is there a function which would format something like

```
="This asteroid is " & SCI_NOTATION(A1) & " kilograms"
```

?

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se] Please add some sample data and the expected results. P.S. Google Sheets several features that help to find built-in functions, i.e. the Help menu has a link to list of functions. It will be nice if you show what you have tried and if you include a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely:

`= "This asteroid is " & text(A1, "0.00E+00") & " kilograms."`